# python-poppler-qt5 install error on win7

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, poppler

[image]

Direct installation of no, the named sipdistutils module python-poppler-qt5 problem, so I found a place on the Internet from the python-poppler-qt5 folder, there is a mistake in the image above

My environment: python3.4 pyqt5.4

I want to use pyqt5 to make a PDF reader.

Answer (score 1):

You must also install the poppler-qt5 library. Python-poppler-qt5 is
only the python binding for the library.

See https://sourceforge.net/projects/poppler-win32/